# HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization with SpringBoot and Hibernate and JPA Repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-jpa

HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization when trying to run spring-boot application. While running mvn spring-boot:run command, the logs show repositories initialized and server starts  and is in running state but throws exception during hikari pool initialization!

Able to connect to the DB using pgAdmin but not able to connect from the application. The code from application.properties is below.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql:/34.93.135.89:5433/mtt_04_dec_22
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= justdoit@mtt
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= none
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000 
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=30
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

And Hikari debug logs

```
 PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-02 11:30:24.569  INFO 14176 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2022-12-02 11:30:24.791  INFO 14176 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2022-12-02 11:30:24.947 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : HikariPool-1 - configuration:
2022-12-02 11:30:24.950 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : allowPoolSuspension.............false
2022-12-02 11:30:24.950 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : autoCommit......................true
2022-12-02 11:30:24.951 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : catalog.........................none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.951 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionInitSql...............none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.951 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTestQuery.............none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.952 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : connectionTimeout...............30000
2022-12-02 11:30:24.952 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSource......................none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.952 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceClassName.............none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.952 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceJNDI..................none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.953 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
2022-12-02 11:30:24.953 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
2022-12-02 11:30:24.953 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : exceptionOverrideClassName......none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.954 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckProperties...........{}
2022-12-02 11:30:24.954 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : healthCheckRegistry.............none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.954 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : idleTimeout.....................600000
2022-12-02 11:30:24.954 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : initializationFailTimeout.......1
2022-12-02 11:30:24.955 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : isolateInternalQueries..........false
2022-12-02 11:30:24.955 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:postgresql:/35.200.211.39:5432/mtt_04_dec_22
2022-12-02 11:30:24.955 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : leakDetectionThreshold..........0
2022-12-02 11:30:24.955 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maxLifetime.....................30000
2022-12-02 11:30:24.956 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : maximumPoolSize.................30
2022-12-02 11:30:24.956 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricRegistry..................none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.956 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : metricsTrackerFactory...........none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.956 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : minimumIdle.....................30
2022-12-02 11:30:24.956 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : password........................<masked>
2022-12-02 11:30:24.957 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : poolName........................"HikariPool-1"
2022-12-02 11:30:24.957 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : readOnly........................false
2022-12-02 11:30:24.957 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : registerMbeans..................false
2022-12-02 11:30:24.957 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : scheduledExecutor...............none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.957 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : schema..........................none
2022-12-02 11:30:24.958 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : threadFactory...................internal
2022-12-02 11:30:24.958 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : transactionIsolation............default
2022-12-02 11:30:24.958 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : username........................"postgres"
2022-12-02 11:30:24.959 DEBUG 14176 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : validationTimeout...............5000
```

EXCEPTION ON CONSOLE LOOKS LIKE:

```
HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2022-12-02 09:26:51.258  INFO 14888 --- [           main] org.sadisha.backend.service.Main         : Starting Main on DESKTOP-991KNCS with PID 14888 (C:\mttbe\mtt-be\target\classes started by Admin in C:\mttbe\mtt-be)
2022-12-02 09:26:51.265  INFO 14888 --- [           main] org.sadisha.backend.service.Main         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-12-02 09:26:52.481  INFO 14888 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2022-12-02 09:26:52.715  INFO 14888 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 220ms. Found 11 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-02 09:26:53.776  INFO 14888 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-02 09:26:53.793  INFO 14888 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-02 09:26:53.794  INFO 14888 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2022-12-02 09:26:54.042  INFO 14888 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-02 09:26:54.043  INFO 14888 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2655 ms
2022-12-02 09:26:54.178  INFO 14888 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-02 09:26:57.285 ERROR 14888 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.isEmbedded(DataSourceInitializer.java:137) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.isEnabled(DataSourceInitializer.java:129) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.createSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `application.properties`

change this :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:/34.93.135.89:5433/mtt_04_dec_22
```

postgresql defaulty adress is `5432` not `5433`. probably this is the reason of error

here is you wrote: `34.93.135.89:5433`

Comment: No, clearly thats not the port issue as Iam able to connect from pgAdmin using 5433

Answer (score 0):

Please try after changing this:

```
jdbc:postgresql:/34.93.135.89:5433/mtt_04_dec_22
```

to

```
jdbc:postgresql://34.93.135.89:5433/mtt_04_dec_22
```

with the missing '/'